# Istio RouteRules doesn't work together

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, istio

I have two Istio `RouteRule`s for `httpDelay`:

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: RouteRule
metadata:
  name: foo-delay
spec:
  destination:
    name: foo-server
  precedence: 5
  route:
  - labels:
      serving: "true"
  httpFault:
    delay:
      fixedDelay: 7.000s
      percent: 100
```

And for `httpReqTimeout`:

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: RouteRule
metadata:
  name: foo-timeout-default
spec:
  destination:
    name: foo-server
  route:
  - labels:
      serving: "true"
  httpReqTimeout:
    simpleTimeout:
      timeout: 5s
  precedence: 3
```

However, I'm not able to make both of these `RouteRules` to work together. For this configuration, I have a delay to `foo-server` but request timeout doesn't work so I receive the data from the `foo-server`. I have tried to change the `httpDelay` rule `precedence: 2`. In this case don't get any delay at all, and I presume that the `httpReqTimeout` works fine.
In both cases I can see that both rules are created:

```
>istioctl get routerules
NAME                KIND                    NAMESPACE
foo-delay           RouteRule.v1alpha2.config.istio.io  default
foo-timeout-default RouteRule.v1alpha2.config.istio.io  default
```

Why doesn't these two `RouteRules` work together?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things happening here.  RouteRule "precedence" in Istio does not infer merging.  So the rule with the highest precedence and matching criteria will match first and all others are ignored by the envoy proxy.  Additionally, even if you merge these two rules into one single rule, unfortunately envoy cannot handle this scenario.  Envoy is written such that faults apply before any timeout/retry

Comment: That's a pity. But are you sure that only one rule is applied in any scenario? The documentation says that `Rules with higher precedence values are evaluated first `.